# Vectorizing variable creation from regexp matching in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is it possible to vectorize the loop below?

```
% String to parse (we want to create variables that are defined implicitly in the string):
parseStr = 'cubeId=001000_X=10_Y=10_Z=10_minX=8590_maxX=9200_minY=8590_maxY=9200_minZ=87_maxZ=95';

% Splitting string for regexp   
matchStr = '=|_';

[start_idx, end_idx, extents, matches, tokens, names, splits] = ...
   regexp(parseStr, matchStr);   

% Inspecting the splits
>> splits
splits = 
  Columns 1 through 8
    'cubeId'    '001000'    'X'    '10'    'Y'    '10'    'Z'    '10'
  Columns 9 through 15
    'minX'    '8590'    'maxX'    '9200'    'minY'    '8590'    'maxY'
  Columns 16 through 20
    '9200'    'minZ'    '87'    'maxZ'    '95'

% Loop that we are interested in vectorizing:
for ix = 1:2:numel(splits)
   fields.(splits{ix}) = splits{ix+1};
end

% Result:
>>fields
fields = 
    cubeId: '000900'
         X: '10'
         Y: '9'
         Z: '10'
      minX: '8590'
      maxX: '9200'
      minY: '7590'
      maxY: '8610'
      minZ: '87'
      maxZ: '95'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CELL2STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2struct.html)

```
cell2struct(splits(2:2:end),splits(1:2:end),2)
ans = 
    cubeId: '001000'
         X: '10'
         Y: '10'
         Z: '10'
      minX: '8590'
      maxX: '9200'
      minY: '8590'
      maxY: '9200'
      minZ: '87'
      maxZ: '95'
```

If you want to have the fields contain numbers, you can instead write

```
cell2struct(cellfun(@str2double,splits(2:2:end),'uniformOutput',false),splits(1:2:end),2)
```

---

Additionally, you can modify your regular expression, so that it returns a struct right away (I didn't type up the entire expression, sorry):

```
regexp(parseStr,'cubeId=(?<cubeId>\d+)_X=(?<X>\d+)','names')
ans = 
    cubeId: '001000'
         X: '10'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly vectorizing and only works if your intention is to create `fields` from scratch rather than updating an existing struct, but:

```
fields = struct(splits{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cellfun does not vectorise your code. Instead it has an internal loop that goes through the arguments.

The above code cannot be vectorised because it is a list of strings. No matter what you will have to call at some point some for loop.

In fact the cellfun solution with a call to cell2struct is slower because you need to make extract calls between functions.

On my machine the for loop requires 0.0008 seconds at most and the cellfun solution 0.0015sec at best.